# Find and replace function using macro

Tags: vba

I want to perform 'find and replace' function in column V using macro. I have previously recorded macro and the VBA is as per below.

But no changes are visible when I run the macro. Appreciate your help!

Or suggest an easier VBA for the 'find and replace' function.

`Columns("V:V").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Fixed Line", Replacement:="Fixed Voice", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="Fixed Code", Replacement:="Fixed Voice", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False`

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
columns(22).replace "Fixed Line", "Fixed Voice"
columns(22).replace "Fixed Code", "Fixed Voice"
```

Comment: Why exactly would this work where the OP's code didn't? You just made a few cosmetic changes. I'm not being facetious — I just would like to get the idea.

Comment: I tested it and it worked, I didn't test the original code